# Shiny R: two selectizeInput menus that need to update each other (mutually exclusive selections)

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js, multipleselection, selectinput

Very new to Shiny here, I have a module like the one below where I just want 2 `SelectizeInput` menus with the same options each.

The trick is that they have to be mutually exclusive, so I understand I have to use `updateSelectizeInput` to update the selected options in one menu based on the selected options in the other.

This should work in such a way that if I select one option in one menu, it has to be removed from the selected options in the other menu, and vice versa.

I understand the moving pieces here, but I am not sure where to place them and how to finally accomplish this.

This is what I have so far:

```
mod_saving_side_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyalert::useShinyalert(),

    uiOutput(outputId = ns("positive_markers")),
    uiOutput(outputId = ns("negative_markers"))
 
  )
}


mod_saving_side_server <- function(id, r){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
 
    output$positive_markers <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput(inputId = ns("pos_markers"), label = "Positive:",
                     choices = LETTERS
                     selected = LETTERS[1],
                     multiple = TRUE)
    })
 
    output$negative_markers <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput(inputId = ns("neg_markers"), label = "Negative:",
                     choices = LETTERS,
                     selected = LETTERS[2],
                     multiple = TRUE)
    })

    # add selected markers to the reactive values
    observeEvent(input$pos_markers, {
      r$pos_markers <- input$pos_markers
      #selected_markers <- ALL EXCEPT pos_markers
      #updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "neg_markers", selected = selected_markers)
    })
    observeEvent(input$neg_markers , {
      r$neg_markers <- input$neg_markers
      #selected_markers <- ALL EXCEPT neg_markers
      #updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "pos_markers", selected = selected_markers)
    })
    
  })
}
```

Not sure if this is a standalone MWE... a side question would be how to make one with the above... Many thanks!

Comment: What is the argument `r` to `mod_saving_side_server` suppose to be? It doesn't seem like you need `shinyjs` and `shinyalert` for MWE. You'll also need `library(shiny)` for it to be a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you asked.

I removed the extra calls to `shinyjs` and `shinyalert` and added call to `library(shiny)` to make it a MWE. I removed the argument `r` to the server call.

I've also moved the input to the UI, removed the `uiOutput` and `renderUI` as it wasn't needed in this case (I'm not sure if the are needed for other parts of your code). Then taking `setdiff` of the options gives you the new set to update the `selectizeInput` with.

I've also added code at the bottom to run and test the app.

```
library(shiny)


mod_saving_side_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectizeInput(inputId = ns("pos_markers"), label = "Positive:",
                   choices = LETTERS,
                   selected = LETTERS[1],
                   multiple = TRUE),
    selectizeInput(inputId = ns("neg_markers"), label = "Negative:",
                   choices = LETTERS,
                   selected = LETTERS[2],
                   multiple = TRUE)
    
  )
}


mod_saving_side_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    # add selected markers to the reactive values
    observeEvent(input$neg_markers, {
      selected_pos_markers <- input$pos_markers
      selected_markers <- setdiff(selected_pos_markers, input$neg_markers)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "pos_markers", selected = selected_markers)
    })
    observeEvent(input$pos_markers , {
      selected_neg_markers <- input$neg_markers
      selected_markers <- setdiff(selected_neg_markers, input$pos_markers)
      updateSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "neg_markers", selected = selected_markers)
    })
    
  })
}

demoApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    mod_saving_side_ui("demo")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    mod_saving_side_server("demo")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

demoApp()
```

Comment: Thanks! works as expected. I still had to keep some stuff from my code as I need the reactive `r` to pass information around (using golem).

Comment: Also many thanks for making it a MWE! Will try to stick to that when asking new questions!